# New to Objective-C and can't find Foundation tool in Xcode package

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.3

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and trying to follow along with the "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" book and it is stating to go to New Project --> Mac OS X and select Command Line Utility --> Then select Foundation Tool on the right hand side. I see Command Line Utility but I don't see Foundation tool so that I can follow along with the book  Can someone assist me possibly as I am new to Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the "Next" button when you start setting up your new project and you'll see this screen in Xcode 4:

[image]

It's one screen *beyond* where you choose what kind of app (iOS or MacOS, GUI or command line, etc.) you want to create.

Answer (score 4):

Just proceed and select in drop down

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know we could upload pictures!  My apologies for no screenshots and maybe the lack of clarity of what my problem was.  This is my first time using this new MacBook :(  Thank you much Vikinggosegundo!!!